# Group by DataFrame based on consecutive ordered values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group a dataframe based on order of values.
Here is my sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 1},
               {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 2},
               {'c1': 'v2', 'c2': 3},
               {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 4},
               {'c1': 'v2', 'c2': 5},
               {'c1': 'v2', 'c2': 6},
               {'c1': 'v3', 'c2': 7}])
df['test'] = 'test'
df1 = df.groupby(['test', 'c1'])['c2'].describe()[['min', 'max']]
print(df1)
```

here is the result:

```
         min  max
test c1          
test v1  1.0  4.0
     v2  3.0  6.0
     v3  7.0  7.0
```

but i'm looking for the possibility to get following result:

```
         min  max
test c1          
test v1  1.0  2.0
     v2  3.0  3.0
     v1  4.0  4.0
     v2  5.0  6.0
     v3  7.0  7.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['test', 'c1', df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift()).cumsum()]).c2.describe()[['min', 'max']].droplevel(2)
```

result:

```
         min  max
test c1          
test v1  1.0  2.0
     v1  4.0  4.0
     v2  3.0  3.0
     v2  5.0  6.0
     v3  7.0  7.0
```

Note usage of [pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) method at the end of transformations, which removes level from dataframe multiindex.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. i've add the sort_index from @HenryYik proposal and got expected result. Thanks a lot to you both, guys.

`df1 = df.groupby(['test', 'c1', df.c1.ne(df.c1.shift()).cumsum()]).c2.describe()[['min', 'max']].sort_index(level=2).droplevel(2)`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need to group by consecutive `c1`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(group=df["c1"].ne(df["c1"].shift()).cumsum())
         .groupby(['test', 'c1', "group"])['c2'].describe()[['min', 'max']]
         .sort_index(level=2))

print(df1)

               min  max
test c1 group          
test v1 1      1.0  2.0
     v2 2      3.0  3.0
     v1 3      4.0  4.0
     v2 4      5.0  6.0
     v3 5      7.0  7.0
```